# Should I use byte or int?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I recall having read somewhere that it is better (in terms of performance) to use Int32, even if you only require Byte. It applies (supposedly) only to cases where you do not care about the storage. Is this valid?

For example, I need a variable that will hold a day of week. Do I

```
int dayOfWeek;
```

or

```
byte dayOfWeek;
```

**EDIT**:
Guys, I am aware of DayOfWeek enum. The question is about something else.

Comment: For that _particular_ example I wouldn't use an int _or_ a byte. An enum would be better in that case (what does 2 mean? Tuesday? Monday?). I know you're generalizing, but some specific cases might be better handled with something other than a strict numeric type.

Comment: As far as efficiency goes - you can't really tell without profiling.  If you're not profiling, you're not optimizing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Usually yes, a 32 bit integer will perform slightly better because it is already properly aligned for native CPU instructions. You should only use a smaller sized numeric type when you actually need to store something of that size.

Comment: By "store" you mean storing in database or file?

Comment: Yes. Or if you are interacting with a native application that is expecting a byte sized bit of data.

Comment: Well, it can still be a good choice to use byte over int if they're in a large array which is consuming too much memory.

Comment: Right. You chose it for memory reasons, not performance reasons.

Comment: @niaher "Store" as in store in memory. Items are stored in files as a sequence of bytes, so if you're worried about disk space you should use bytes. Items are processed by your CPU in 32- or 64-bit integers (depending on your processor) so any item that's less than that amount will be "upgraded" to a 32- or 64-bit representation for runtime computation.

Comment: Also, in the BCL, binary data is more often given as a `byte[]` (array of octets) rather than an `int[]` or `uint[]`, so `byte` seems to be preferred in that situation. Of course if you use `int[]` you restrict yourself to the case where the length of the data is an integral multiple of 32 bits (as opposed to 8 bits), and that may be a problem or an advantage depending on context.

Answer (score 13):

You should use the DayOfWeek enum, unless there's a strong reason not to.

```
DayOfWeek day = DayOfWeek.Friday;
```

To explain, since I was downvoted:

The *correctness* of your code is almost always more critical than the *performance*, especially in cases where we're talking this small of a difference.  If using an enum or a class representing the semantics of the data (whether it's the DayOfWeek enum, or another enum, or a Gallons or Feet class) makes your code clearer or more maintainable, it will help you get to the point where you can safely optimize.

```
int z;
int x = 3;
int y = 4;
z = x + y;
```

That may compile.  But there's no way to know if it's doing anything sane or not.

```
Gallons z;
Gallons x = new Gallons(3);
Feet y = new Feet(4);
z = x + y;
```

This won't compile, and even looking at it it's obvious why not - adding Gallons to Feet *makes no sense*.

Comment: Yes.  I believe you use it to measure the volume of *Apple-Kumquats*.

Comment: Agreed. Misunderstanding what a variable represents probably accounts for more errors than memory or disk space constraints ever do!

Answer (score 8):

My default position is to try to use strong types to add constraints to values - where you know those in advance. Thus in your example, it may be preferable to use `byte dayOfWeek` because it is closer to your desired value range.

Here is my reasoning; with the example of storing and passing a year-part of a date. The year part - when considering other parts of the system that include SQL Server DateTimes, is constrained to 1753 through to 9999 (note C#'s possible range for DateTime is different!) Thus a `short` covers my possible values and if I try to pass anything larger the compiler will warn me before the code will compile.  Unfortunately, in this particular example, the C# DateTime.Year property will return an int - thus forcing me to cast the result if I need to pass e.g. `DateTime.Now.Year` into my function.

This starting-position is driven by considerations of long-term storage of data, assuming 'millions of rows' and disk space - even though it is cheap (it is far less cheap when you are hosted and running a SAN or similar).

In another DB example, I will use smaller types such as byte (SQL Server tinyint) for lookup ID's where I am confident that there will not be many lookup types, through to long (SQL Server bigint) for id's where there are likely to be more records. i.e. to cover transactional records.

So my rules of thumb:

1. Go for correctness first if possible. Use DayOfWeek in your example, of course :)
2. Go for a type of appropriate size thus making use of compiler safety checks giving you errors at the earliest possible time;
3. ...but offset against extreme performance needs and simplicity, especially where long-term storage is not involved, or where we are considering a lookup (low row count) table rather than a transactional (high row count) one.

In the interests of clarity, DB storage tends not to shrink as quickly as you expect by shrinking column types from bigint to smaller types. This is both because of padding to word boundaries and page-size issues internal to the DB. However, you probably store every data item several times in your DB, perhaps through storing historic records as they change, and also keeping the last few days of backups and log backups. So saving a few percent of your storage needs will have long term savings in storage cost.

I have never personally experienced issues where the in-memory performance of bytes vs. ints has been an issue, but I have wasted hours and hours having to reallocate disk space and have live servers entirely stall because there was no one person available to monitor and manage such things.

Comment: +1 for actually getting use out of strong typing.  The biggest benefit of strong typing is *not* IntelliSense!

Answer (score 6):

Use an int. Computer memory is addressed by "words," which are usually 4 bytes long. What this means is that if you want to get one byte of data from memory, the CPU has to retrieve the entire 4-byte word from RAM and then perform some extra steps to isolate the single byte that you're interested in. When thinking about performance, it will be a lot easier for the CPU to retrieve a whole word and be done with it.

Actually in all reality, you won't notice any difference between the two as far as performance is concerned (except in rare, extreme circumstances). That's why I like to use int instead of byte, because you can store bigger numbers with pretty much no penalty.

Comment: If the performance won't suffer much, then I prefer to stick with the semantics, and use byte where I only need a byte. This way I can avoid some unexpected bugs.

Comment: Actually, the CPU has to retrieve the entire cache line from RAM, and then the four byte word from cache, and then the byte that's desired

Answer (score 4):

In terms of storage amount, use `byte` and in terms of cpu performance, use `int`.

Comment: So `byte` works like any other integer? Basically. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Common_integral_data_types

Answer (score 2):

<strike>System.DayOfWeek</strike>

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx)

Most of the time use int. Not for performance but simplicity.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. DayOfWeek variable was just an example.

Comment: @niaher - Remember us programmers are very literal people.

Comment: This got upvotes?  Now it says something completely different.  Chaos reigns.

Comment: Even if it's an example, it's a good point.  Don't use a plain int or byte, unless that's *really* the semantic meaning of what you're storing.  Use a type that encapsulates the semantics of what you're doing.  That can prevent errors such as adding gallons to feet.  Correctness is more important than efficience 90%+ of the time, and correctness gets you to the point where you *can* optimize faster.