# Program speed vs memory usage

Tags: c#, int, byte

I wonder about my program speed. When I use methods like `Array.GetLength(1)` or so it always returns `int` variable. Or when I insert a single number the compiler declares it as `int` again. Do I need to convert them to `byte` variables to lower the memory usage or this will affect my program speed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use byte or int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346394/should-i-use-byte-or-int) (or [Why should I use int instead of a byte or short](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097467/why-should-i-use-int-instead-of-a-byte-or-short-in-c-sharp?lq=1) or [Does using small datatypes  reduce memory usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198240/does-using-small-datatypes-for-example-short-instead-of-int-reduce-memory-usag))

Comment: The easiest way to answer this question is to profile both variances

Comment: fastest size is your native size. 32 bit os? then it is int. 64 bit os? can be "long"

Comment: i think, the most important question is: "do you really need this micro optimizations?" You don't work on a 64K machine with 4.77MHz CPU

Comment: For method variables, `byte` vs `int` won't make the slightest difference whatsoever; IL stack ops only really exist for i8/i4 - i2 and i1 are implemented as i4. If you had an array of 20,000 `int` vs 20,000 `byte`, then *that* might be a worthwhile question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are equally fast as far as arithmetic operations the computer performs on them.

But if you have a large amount of data then `byte` can be significantly faster, purely because of the smaller size:

1. Your CPU cache holds more `byte` objects than `int` objects.
2. Using every element of an array of `byte` objects needs less memory bandwidth than `int` objects.  If you have to use a database or send the data across a network this use of bandwidth becomes a *really* big deal.
3. Your computer RAM can hold more `byte` values before it starts having to use the hard disk as virtual memory.  If your data set was a size where `int` would need virtual memory and `byte` would not, then `byte` will be a lot faster.

The only real downside of bytes is that you end up writing code to convert to and from `int` often, even if this conversion ends up being done for free on the CPU (using a byte transfer to register instead of a word transfer)

Answer (score 4):

Method variables are on the stack (caveat: iterator blocks, captured variables, etc - but don't worry about those). The stack is going to be the same size no matter what you do. If you were talking about grossly over-sized value-types, then the obvious concern would be stack exhaustion (which could perhaps be mitigated via `ref`, but that is not related to this question) - but changing ***local method variables*** from `int` to `byte` will not change anything. In fact, IIRC the IL stack operations are *only defined* in terms of 4 or 8 byte values.

Basically: this won't help at all, so don't worry about it. But it also isn't **even remotely** impacting your application's performance or memory usage. If you want to know what *is*, then profile.

Comment: As an illustration - see the comments on `conv.ovf.u1`, one of the opcodes that casts to a `byte` (specifically, in a `checked` context): "Convert to an unsigned int8 (on the stack as int32) and throw an exception on overflow." - even though it logically converts to `int8`, it is *immediately* actually an `int32` again. What this *actually* does is lop off all except the LSB (checking for overflow), but leave it as an `int32`