# What type should be used for representing time in C#?

Tags: c#, types

I apologize in advance if I have grammar mistakes - English is not my strong side. :)

I am trying to create a code in C# which has 2 variables that represents time: The first contains hours, and the second contains minutes.

My question is simple - what datatype should I use for those variables? on one hand, I should use `byte`, because hours and minutes are between `0` and `255`, but on the other hand - I have read that the CPU works better with `int`. So which one should I use?

Here is the answer I have read which compares between `int` and `byte` from the perspective of CPU performance: [Why should I use int instead of a byte or short in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097467/why-should-i-use-int-instead-of-a-byte-or-short-in-c-sharp)

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use byte or int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346394/should-i-use-byte-or-int)

Comment: And yes, past the 8 bit processor era, it's generally not "faster" to use 8 bits. It may help with storage, but not with speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your system requirement. If you're developing an application for Windows desktop or server, you can expect that you will have a lot of RAM.

So you can use `System.Int32`, cause modern CPUs are optimized for this type processing.

If you're developing an application for mobile platform or for embedded devices, then an amount of RAM can be limited, where limit can be 512Mb or 1Gb. So if you aren't creating millions of such objects, you can use `System.Int32` again.

Finally, if you want serialize and de-serialize these objects, you may cast them to `System.Byte` at the serialization step.

Answer (score 2):

`TimeSpan` struct is the standard way of representing times in .Net.
However, you can work also with `int` or `byte` to represent seconds, minutes, etc. too. `byte` has an smaller footprint then `int`, but it shouldn't make a big difference.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two different variables for this. Use the dedicated [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type for this purpose.

Comment: My question is more general. If I have a variable that represent small numbers - what datatype should I use? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sipo That's not what you asked. Look at your question *What type should be used for representing time in C#?*

Comment: You are right. I ment that I would still like to have an answer for the general case. English problems, sorry. :)

Comment: @Sipo ok, for general question, you need to find which range your number will fit in. If it fits inside `byte` use `byte`. If it fits short, use short and so forth.