# Is it okay to declare a variable as Byte then convert to Int in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-management, integer, short

So i want to use Byte and Short to decrease memory usage, but some methods asks explicitly for Int.

```
private val numberOne : Byte = 50
someMethodAskingInt(numberOne.toInt())
```

If i convert a variable to Int with `.toInt()` will it get more space in memory?
Will it even be worth it to use Byte or Short in those cases?

Comment: this answer here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2346398/6892294

Comment: This may be relevant, but I don't know if Android works the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531235/in-java-is-it-more-efficient-to-use-byte-or-short-instead-of-int-and-float-inst

Comment: Thank you both very much for the answers!

Comment: Just to clarify, the Q&A I linked to talks about the Java Virtual Machine (possibly the HotSpot implementation specifically). But Android uses the "Android Runtime" (not a JVM implementation), if I'm not mistaken, so that Q&A may not apply.

Comment: In practice this won’t save you any memory. As far as I know, on most VMs bytes and shorts only save memory as part of ByteArrays, ShortArrays, ByteBuffers, and ShortBuffers.